# Search using UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I have looked everywhere and there doesn't seem to be a clear example. I am trying to achieve this, where the textField will act as a searchBar then the user would be able to add that item:
[image]

Most example seem to use UI SearchBar and a tableView where it displays the filtered results. But there is no real example that uses just a textField.

My other option is to try and just get an autocompletion where it checks if the character that is inputted matches an array of data, something like this:

Are there any clearer examples or tutorial I can follow? I'm fairly new to programming so I would prefer it be in Swift please.

**Other similar reference:**

http://www.iostutorialjunction.com/2017/04/integrate-search-functionality-in-ios-using-swift3.html

[How to make UITextField behave like a UISearchBar in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446376/how-to-make-uitextfield-behave-like-a-uisearchbar-in-swift)

https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

http://www.matthewhsingleton.com/blog/2016/5/26/predictive-text-table-view-swift-version-of-ray-wenderlich

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZ_S2GHFwW4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtiamBbL5QU&t=975s

[Getting autocomplete to work in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885438/getting-autocomplete-to-work-in-swift)

https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField

Comment: You want a method that run whenever a text is typed? And on the base of that text you want to filter some string in Array right?

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas Correct, please see my updated image as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this task.
You can place a `textField` as well as a `UILabel` exactly behind it.
And When Every you type a word just change the text of that label. Set the Label's textColor to lightGrey color and you will be good to go.
To set a method that invokes every time user type something use below code.

```
//Below line will set a method to textFields value change event.
searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textIsChanging(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)



func textIsChanging(textField: UITextField) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. What do you mean by "place a textField as well as a UILabel exactly behind it", behind what. Also in the function textIsChanging(textField: UITextField) is this where would check if the inputted data is equal to some string in an array?

Comment: Yes this is the method where you will check if the entered text is equal to some string in array or not.
And Go to storyboard place a Label behind UITextField. Give textField a clearColor and on searching a match string just update the uilabel's text not the textField's text. This will give you the effect that you want in you above image

Answer (score 1):

you can use an delegate method `textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField)`, works for me